# Powershell Get-Winevent No events were found that match the specified selection criteria

Tags: powershell

I am writing a Powershell 2.0 script that parses a folder of offline .evtx event logs and generates a csv with specified output. I am only looking for certain event IDs and I am only outputting certain fields to the csv. The problem I run into arises when a specified event ID does not exist in a .evtx file; it generates an error: "Get-WinEvent: No events were found that match the specified selection criteria" (NoMatchingEventsFound). This makes sense, but is there a way to write it in a way to "not care" if the event ID exists and continue to parse? (I am only looking for specific existences of these chosen IDs, and I don't care if they don't exist) Here is my code:

```
 $ReviewFile = ("\\thepath\" + (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MMM-yy") + " Review.csv")
If (Test-Path $Reviewfile){Remove-Item $ReviewFile}
 $EventLogIDs = "4476","4741","4742" # etc...I have quite a number of IDs
 Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="\\evtxpath\" + (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd") + "\*Security*";id=@($EventLogIDs);}|
 Select-Object Id,LevelDisplayName,Message,MachineName,RecordId,TaskDisplayName | Export-CSV $ServerReviewFile
```

I have tried to add -ErrorAction silentlycontinue but it skips the entire hashtable.
I was thinking along the lines of maybe looping through an eventID array with a try and catch within the loop. Would that work? How would that affect the syntax of the hashtable generation code? Any other suggestions? Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use a try catch:

```
$EventLogIDs = @("4476", "4741", "4742")

ForEach($EvtxFileInfo in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\EvtxFolder\'))
{
    $ReviewFile = ("\\ThePath\" + (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MMM-yy") +
        " Review.csv")

    if (Test-Path $ReviewFile) { Remove-Item $ReviewFile }

    try 
    {
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ 
                Path = $EvtxFileInfo.FullName;  # or your way
                Id = $EventLogIDs;
            } | 
            Select Id, LevelDisplayName, Message, MachineName, RecordId, TaskDisplayName | 
            Export-Csv $ReviewFile -NoTypeInfo
    }
    catch  # plain catch = catch everything
    {
        # do nothing
    }
}
```

More info about: [ForEach](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847816.aspx) 
More info about: [Try Catch (Finally)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) 
Reference: [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for that. It looks like its giving me the same error. (because I am looping through each evtx file and if the ID does not exist in the evtx it generates the exception.) However, with your code, I think I can modify it to cycle through each event ID for each Evtx. It will probably take a lot longer to run, but then it should log all the event IDs that do exist. I will post it for others when I get it working. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding why it would stop just because it can't find one event ID.  Are you using the `-FilterHashTable` parameter?  The key word there is _filter_.  There's no requirement that it find _all_ event IDs.

Comment: You're right. It works. I was still getting the error because ALL of the test event IDs I was putting in were not in the .evtx files. (I replaced some of them with ones that did exist in the logs and it worked.) Cheers